# Debian Apt Connection Failed despite wget working

Tags: debian, apt

For some reason my Debian 10 box cannot use Apt to get any connections. There is no proxy, I have no custom settings in apt.conf.d and I can even use wget to the exact same IP and port that Apt just failed at and succeed...

```
Err:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 libpq-dev amd64 11.12-0+deb10u1
  Connection failed [IP: 151.101.250.132 80]
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 binutils-common amd64 2.31.1-16
  Connection failed [IP: 151.101.250.132 80]
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libbinutils amd64 2.31.1-16
  Connection failed [IP: 151.101.250.132 80]
Err:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 libssl-dev amd64 1.1.1d-0+deb10u6
  Connection failed [IP: 151.101.250.132 80]
Err:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu amd64 2.31.1-16
  Connection failed [IP: 151.101.250.132 80]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 binutils amd64 2.31.1-16 [56.8 kB]
0% [Waiting for headers]
```

```
$ sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# 

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
```

```
$ wget http://deb.debian.org/debian
--2021-06-30 14:04:43--  http://deb.debian.org/debian
Resolving deb.debian.org (deb.debian.org)... 199.232.130.132, 2a04:4e42:60::644
Connecting to deb.debian.org (deb.debian.org)|199.232.130.132|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ [following]
--2021-06-30 14:04:43--  http://ftp.debian.org/debian/
Resolving ftp.debian.org (ftp.debian.org)... 199.232.130.132, 2a04:4e42:60::644
Reusing existing connection to deb.debian.org:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 6103 (6.0K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘debian’

debian                                                                          100%[====================================>]   5.96K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2021-06-30 14:04:44 (274 MB/s) - ‘debian’ saved [6103/6103]

$ wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security
--2021-06-30 14:04:56--  http://security.debian.org/debian-security
Resolving security.debian.org (security.debian.org)... 151.101.194.132, 151.101.2.132, 151.101.130.132, ...
Connecting to security.debian.org (security.debian.org)|151.101.194.132|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ [following]
--2021-06-30 14:04:57--  http://security.debian.org/debian-security/
Reusing existing connection to security.debian.org:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1972 (1.9K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘debian-security’

debian-security                                                                 100%[====================================>]   1.93K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2021-06-30 14:04:57 (77.6 MB/s) - ‘debian-security’ saved [1972/1972]
```

I see no new logs in /var/log/apt/history.log or any log for that matter.

Why is apt failing here and how can I fix it?

Comment: I wonder if the 151.101.250.132 IP is valid for security.debian.org; I see that wget resolves it to a similar but different IP (151.101.194.132). Additionally, I wonder if apt is receiving the same 301 redirect and is not following it. (Untested ideas)

Comment: Indeed, two online DNS resolvers don't pick up 250.132 as an IP for security.debian.org

Comment: slip of finger in /etc/hosts ?

Comment: But I can retrieve a file from this IP without problem: `curl -v --connect-to security.debian.org:80:151.101.250.132:80 http://security.debian.org/dists/buster/updates/InRelease`

Comment: Perhaps `apt-get -oDebug::Acquire::http=on` reveals something. (In general look at  `man apt.conf` - DEBUG section at end ). Also appending a `/` at end of path to wget to not get the 301 redirect (+ in general use `-S` option for wget when comparing can be nice).

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Above mentioned http debug prints helped me identify the problem. The curl/wget command worked. But when you add the header - "User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (2.2.4)", curl stops working. apt-get was using the same user agent string. I got it to work using a different mirror instead.